# Difference in FFT between IDL and Python

Tags: python, scipy, fft, idl, idl-programming-language

I'm passing some simple IDL code to Python. However the returned FFT values form the SciPy/NumPy packages is different than the IDL one and I can't find out why.

Reducing it all to a simple example of 8 elements I found that the SciPy/NumPy routines return values that are 8 (2^3) times bigger than the IDL ones (a normalization problem I thought).

Here is the example code (copied from [here](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-3630ad1b5548a4e75ae976d678853e3a197c84fe)) in both languages:

### IDL

```
signal = ([-2., 8., -6., 4., 1., 0., 3., 5.])
fourier = fft(signal)
print, fourier
```

returns

> (      1.62500,      0.00000) (     0.420495,     0.506282) ( 0.250000,     0.125000) (     -1.17050,     -1.74372) (     -2.62500,     -0.00000) (     -1.17050,      1.74372) (     0.250000,    -0.125000) (     0.420495,    -0.506282)

### Python

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as N
…
signal = N.array([-2., 8., -6., 4., 1., 0., 3., 5.])
fourier = fft(signal)
print fourier
```

returns

> [ 13. +0.j , 3.36396103 +4.05025253j, 2. +1.j , -9.36396103-13.94974747j,  -21. +0.j , -9.36396103+13.94974747j,  2. -1.j , 3.36396103 -4.05025253j]

I did it with the NumPy package and I got the same results. I tried also `print fft(signal, 8 )` just in case but it returned the same, as expected.

However that's not all, coming back to my real array of 256 elements I found that the difference was no longer 8 or 256, but 256*8! it's just insane.

Although I worked around the problem I NEED to know why there is that difference.

**Solved:** It was just the normalization, at some point I divided the IDL 256 array by a factor of 8 that I forgot to remove. In Dougal's answer there is the documentation that I missed.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried the same code as you and I have the same results. Where is that 8 factor modifying the results?

Comment: IDL divides by N on the forward transform, which happens to be 8 here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IDL and numpy use slightly different definitions of the DFT. Numpy's is (from [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details)):

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [scipy.org](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/_images/math/6bbd972502306a4225d33ac6919fc6fc8244f67d.png))</sub>

while IDL's is (from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125085618/http://www.physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/idl_html_help/F4.html)):

[image]

Numpy's `m` is the same as IDL's `x`, `k` is `u`, `n` is `N`. I think `a_m` and `f(x)` are the same thing as well. So the factor of `1/N` is the obvious difference, explaining the difference of 8 in your 8-elt case.

I'm not sure about the 256*8 one for the 256-elt case; could you maybe post the original array and both outputs somewhere? (Does this happen for all 256-elt arrays? What about other sizes? I don't have IDL....)

Comment: Sorry, i got to the fft links on the top and i did not scrooll down to the documentation in scipy case... Anyway i tried with longer and shorter arrays and the normalization seems to be the problem, but the 256 long vector that i'm using is still wrong by the 8 factor. I do that `print len(matflux[i,:]), fft(matflux[i,:]` where the len is 256

Comment: Sorry, I've tried the same code as you and I have the same results. Where is that 8 factor modifying the results?